# PG::UndefinedObject: ERROR: type "integter" does not exist - Postgresql - Docker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, docker, docker-compose

My Rails app runs in docker together with postgresql. However, when I want to create new columns for a table, I run the migration and I get an error:

```
# docker command to run migrate
docker-compose run rails rails db:migrate

# get error:
PG::UndefinedObject: ERROR:  type "integter" does not exist
LINE 1: ALTER TABLE "events" ADD "min_register_confirmed" integter
```

Here is my migration file:

```
class AddMinRegisterConfirmedToEvents < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    add_column :events, :min_register_confirmed, :integter#, default: 0

    Event.update_all(min_register_confirmed: 100)
  end
end
```

I've tried to find solution on the internet, but it seems like nobody gets the same error as me. Please help!

Comment: `integter` ??? it should be `integer `

Comment: @Salil Thank you! You saved my life, I mistyped one character of type integer. =))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You misspelled the type `integer`

Change

```
add_column :events, :min_register_confirmed, :integter#, default: 0
```

To

```
add_column :events, :min_register_confirmed, :integer
```